# Clear specific cached result in typeahead

Tags: jquery, caching, typeahead, twitter-typeahead, bloodhound

I have the following requirement: `When a suggestion is selected, that suggestion should not appear again for future searches using the same query`.

On the server side, I am excluding results that have already been selected and added to my object; but since typeahead caches results, these are appearing in the suggestions for future searches using the same query.

I know it's possible to destroy the typeahead instance (http://tosbourn.com/refreshing-local-data-with-typeahead-js/) but I want to implement an optimal solution where I only clear the cache item that corresponds to the last query. I think I can do this inside the `selected` handler:

```
 .on('typeahead:selected', function(e, datum, dataset) 
      {
          var $selectedDatum = datum;
          $(this).val($selectedDatum.Name);

          // Posts the selected id and updated the saved object
          addItem($selectedDatum.Id, $selectedDatum.Name);

          // TODO: pass current query to cache-clear function
          // clearCache(e.query);

          return false;
  });
```

Is this possible or should I just accept that I need to clear the result cache? Perhaps I should be trying this in Bloodhound but not sure where to put the code.